# BluRay drive gets no power

Tags: ps3

The BluRay drive went dead and I replaced it twice with new ones, and there is still no power getting to it. I changed the ribbons (cables?) twice. The PS3 starts up and I can play downloaded games. Only the  BluRay drive doesn't get power.

It's a PS3 Slim.

Comment: If it's not getting power, have you been plugging in the power cable correctly?

Comment: Question belongs to SuperUser.com

Comment: @DrFish I think the PS3 qualifies as game-specific hardware.

Comment: @DrFish SuperUser specifically forbid gaming specific hardware, including consoles.

Comment: Well, good to know then. I retracted my close vote and edited the question to be more readable.